# entropy regularization in generative model

Tags: probability, regularization, entropy, generative-models, maximum-entropy

I am wondering if it is possible to use entropy as a regularization in a generative model. For example, in the conjugate model where $x_i \in X$ is observed data and generated from a Normal distribution with unknown $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$:

$x_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

and further assume $\mu$ is generated from a Normal distribution with hyperparameters $\mu_0$ and $v$:

$\mu \sim N(\mu_0, v)$,

and $\sigma^2$ is generated from a Inverse-Gamma distribution with hyperparameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

$\sigma^2 \sim IG(\alpha,\beta)$.

The $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ can be learned by using maximum likelihood (ML) or MAP. My question is: is it possible and correct to futher apply an entropy regularization in the ML objective, i.e., maximize the likelihood and the entropy of $\mu$ to express the uncertainty in $\mu$.